# How to correctly eliminate some entries in a vector [notation]

Tags: notation, vectors

I have a vector of vectors that can be described as:

${A} = \left(a_i \right)_{i=1}^{N}$

I want to discard some of its elements based on some conditions, how can formulate it?

For instance, I have:

${A^R}=(a \mid \forall  a \in {A} \wedge a \in \mathcal{A}^R)$

To denote the vector which only keeps the elements that are contained in the set $\mathcal{A}^R$ and eliminates all other elements.

Is there a better formulation for it?

Comment: I'd call it a tuple instead of a vector (since "vector" implies you have a vector space and the elements are coordinates) and use words to define the operation. (Something like "Let $B=(b_i)_{i=1}^m$ be the tuple obtained by deleting the elements of $A$ that are not in $S$.") If you do this often, you could define notation for it (maybe $A\cap S$ if it's clear that $A$ is to be treated as a tuple and not a set).

Comment: Definitely do not call it a "vector". While a "vector of vectors" is a reasonble thing to define - indeed, matrices can be viewed as such - an ordered collection of elements from which you can add or remove elements based their membership in some other sets violates the fundamental concept of what a vector is, which is a member of some vector space. Vector spaces themselves are collections of elements that can be added together, or multiplied by scalars. There is no clear concept of how to add together ordered collections of different lengths.